# selecting map based on values in the list

Tags: java, java-stream

I have listofMaps and listOfStrings. How can I get only those maps in resultant list with values matching in the listofstring?

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = listofMaps
                                 .stream()
                                 .filter(maps -> maps.containsValue(listOfString))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

if I replace listOfString with actual string like "string" then one map gets selected but not the multiple matching maps.

Comment: Why do you replace `listOfString` with a single string value and expect that `containsValue` should find _a string_ inside list which could be placed inside the map?

Comment: lets say listofmaps is {id=1, name=abc },{id=2, name=xyz }, {id=3, name=stu} and based on listOfString {xyz, stu} I want to select two maps 2nd & 3rd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a value in the map is matched to any possible value in the `listOfStrings`, `anyMatch` needs to be used along with `List::contains`:

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> listofMaps = Arrays.asList(
    Map.of("id", 1, "name", "abc"),
    Map.of("id", 2, "name", "xyz"),
    Map.of("id", 3, "name", "stu")
);

List<String> listOfString = Arrays.asList("abc", "stu");

List<Map<String, Object>> listAnyMatch = listofMaps
        .stream()
        .filter(maps -> maps.values()
                            .stream()
                            .anyMatch(listOfString::contains))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

listAnyMatch.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
{name=abc, id=1}
{name=stu, id=3}
```

Comment: Got it. so, I guess, map.containsvalue() will only work for one value in stream?

Comment: It's rather for a case when you look for an _equal specific_ value.  For example, there's a map like `{id=1, list=["a", "b"]}, {id=2, name="a"}`, then `containsValue(List.of("a", "b"))` would find the first entry.